# 'ExceptionHandlerFactory was not configured properly' on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: jsf, glassfish, glassfish-3, exceptionhandler

I'm trying to handle uncaught exceptions through ExceptionHandler. Following the code in JSF2 complete reference, I've created the classes for my handler. But when I deploy my app, it throws the next stackTrace:

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: exception.ExceptionHandlerFactory
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:643)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:509)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:139)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:993)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: exception.ExceptionHandlerFactory
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:342)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:641)
... 50 more
```

This is my faces-config.xml:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        exception.ExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

ExceptionHandlerFactory.java

```
public class ExceptionHandlerFactory extends javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory {

private transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

public ExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
    ExceptionHandler result = parent.getExceptionHandler();
    result = new CustomExceptionHandler(result);
    return result;
}
```

}

CustomExceptionHandler.java

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

private ExceptionHandler parent;

public CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
    return this.parent;
}

@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i =
            getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
            i.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context =
                (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
        Throwable t = context.getException();

        if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            ViewExpiredException vee = (ViewExpiredException) t;
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            NavigationHandler nav =
                    fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            try {

                fc.getExternalContext().
                        getFlash().put("currentViewId",
                        vee.getViewId());
                nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/login?faces-redirect=true");
                fc.renderResponse();
            } finally {
                i.remove();
            }
        } 
    }

    getWrapped().handle();
}
}
```

Server is Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

I need to to some logic when I get the ViewExpiredException. Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance !!!!

**EDIT:**

As @BalusC pointed, I changed my factory class name, so this is my CustomExceptionHandlerFactory.java:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

    public CustomExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        ExceptionHandler result = parent.getExceptionHandler();
        result = new CustomExceptionHandler(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and my faces-config.xml:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        com.exception.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

I hope this could be helpful for anyone with this silly problem.

Comment: @BalusC I just renamed my factory class, and I agree with you, maybe the ExceptionHandlerFactory was not instantiated correctly, but as you suggested, this handler is working now. Thank you. I post the renamed class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is that you reused the same classname as an existing API class for some unclear reason and got them mixed up in the code.

The `parent` constructor argument (and local variable) has to be of type `javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory`, not of your `exception.ExceptionHandlerFactory`. This wrong type caused that JSF was unable to invoke the constructor and hence the -rather self explaining- *InstantiationException* (it couldn't be instantiated).

Better rename your class to something unique like `CustomExceptionHandlerFactory`.